# Problem with base condition of a recursion problem in Java

Tags: java, function, recursion

in the following code I am unable to understand why is the base condition like that. I don't see "str" getting updated anywhere yet its length becomes "0".

the code:

```java
public class permutations_recursion {
    
    public static void perm(String str, String permutaions) {
        if (str.length() == 0) {
            System.out.println(permutaions);
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            char currChar = str.charAt(i);
            String newStr = str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i + 1);
            perm(newStr, permutaions + currChar);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String str = "abc";
        String permutations = "";
        perm(str, permutations);
    }
}
```

I tried asking chatGPT but it isn't quite helpful. Need an expert's help.

Comment: The function is calling itself recursively with a smaller and smaller string inside the for-loop.

Comment: Keep in mind that the "base case" (at least here) is hit on the last recursive step, but will be the first to print. You can think of it as everything within that base case is executed base-case-first, while everything after is executed base-case-last.

Comment: I would avoid using chatGPT to help with coding problems.  In my limited experience testing it, it generates flawed code.

Comment: Strings dont get updated, they are immutable. The code generates new strings and passes them into the perm function.

Comment: every time the recursive call is called, a new `str` is *created* (new memory location), not related to the previous one. The value of the new `str` is set from the calling arguments, in this case, the value of `newStr` which happens to be one character less then the previous `str` (as you yourself wrote: "*we want to send one character less for the next level of recursion.*")

Comment: But is the str in the base condition actually newStr variable in the recursive function call?

Comment: `String permutations` is misleading. It's just one permutation, basically the result of the function (even though it's a parameter) which is slowly built up using characters pulled from the input string and moved into every possible position. Use plural names for arrays and maps, not single scalar values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you are missing:

```
        String newStr = str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i + 1);
```

This will skip the character in newStr at index i. The full string (which you sometimes want if you want to insert something at a point in a String) would be

```
        String newStr = str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i);
```

Read the definition of this function and try creating some test examples to clarify your understanding.

Comment: skipping a character is the idea. coz we want to send one character less for the next level of recursion.

Comment: @MukundKarki So does this answer your question? If so, please click the green check mark at the top left to mark this question answered.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if we rename some of the variables and slightly re-work how the recursion works?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    String str = "abc";
    perm(str, "");
} 

public static void perm(String strCharPool, String permutations) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strCharPool.length(); i++) {
        char currChar = strCharPool.charAt(i);          
        String newStrWithoutCurrChar = strCharPool.substring(0, i) + strCharPool.substring(i + 1);
        String newPerm = permutations + currChar;
        if (newStrWithoutCurrChar.length() == 0) {
            System.out.println(newPerm);
        }
        else {
            perm(newStrWithoutCurrChar, newPerm);
        }          
    }
}
```